# Bash - Read response to copy files or directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script to copy a file based on user response. An example of what I am trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is the name of the user?: "
read RESPONSE
cp /home/$RESPONSE/file.txt /home/$RESPONSE/backup/file_backup.txt
```

However, my copy command doesn't seem to be accepting the read variable correctly.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What *exactly* is wrong? If the username has a space in it, or a literal backslash, or can be evaluated as a glob, the bugs are pretty obvious -- but you'll need to be more specific about the *exact* behavior observed. "Doesn't seem to be accepting" -- how do you know? What's the exact input, and the exact error in the output?

Comment: Consider running `bash -x yourscript` to run it with logging for commands invoked. Also, run it through http://shellcheck.net/, and fix what that finds (that's always good advice before asking shell questions here).

Comment: Also, don't use all-caps names for your own variables! All-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the operating system or shell; using lower-case names avoids stepping on those by mistake. See [the relevant standards document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html), paragraph 4 (yes, it's discussing environment variables, but setting a regular shell variable will overwrite a like-named environment variable, so the convention applies in both places).

Comment: Did you try to add double quotes ? `cp "/home/$RESPONSE/file.txt" "/home/$RESPONSE/backup/file_backup.txt"`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou, *nod* -- that's what I pointed the OP to shellcheck for. (Better that they get the habit of checking there than needing to get human direction).

Comment: Yes, good point...

Comment: GeorgeVasiliou: Yeah, I tried that also
CharlesDuffy: Thanks for the suggestions. I've used shellcheck.net in the past and it's not always intuitive. In some of my experience in trying to use that tool it never found issues when there are issues with the script.
I changed the the variable to lowercase and it still doesn't work. This is the output I get:
cp: cannot stat 'home//file.txt': no such file or directory

Comment: The error message implies that the user is not entering a directory name, however it could be that you mis-spelt `RESPONSE` in one of the places you are using it.

Comment: Are you able to run this? `read -p "user?" us; ls -l /home/$us/Desktop`. This runs fine in my bash, even unquoted.

Comment: The code looks OK, but will not work properly if your script has DOS line endings.

Comment: You say the code you post is "an example of what you're trying to do". Does that mean the code you actually run is different? If so, please post the actual code you're having problems with. If you want to abbreviate/simplify/redact, make sure that your simplified version still shows the problem before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. I had some commands in between and then had a second read RESPONSE command that was not required. In other words, as an example, I had this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is the name of the user?: "
read RESPONSE
rsync -a /home/$RESPONSE /backup
read RESPONSE
cp /home/$RESPONSE/file.txt /home/$RESPONSE/backup/file_backup.txt
```

Also,@GeorgeVasiliou had it right, I needed to also include it in quotes. So what works is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What is the name of the user?: "
read response
rsync -a "/home/$response/" /backup
cp "/home/$response/file.txt" "/home/$response/backup/file_backup.txt"
```

Comment: You would probably be better off by checking on your script if the user and the backup folder exist or not before running the script all the way. See my answer.

Comment: In the future, make sure to check that your simplified code in your question has the same problem as the real program you're trying to create a reproducer for.

Answer (score 1):

The following code achieves what you want. It also checks to see if the user exists, and if the user has created a /backup/ folder before attempting to save the file (if user doesn't exist, then /home/user/... should also not exist and the script would fail).

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is the name of the user?: "
read response
checkuser1="$(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | grep -si "$response")"
if [ -z "$checkuser1" ]; then echo "No user with this name has been located!"; exit; fi
if [ ! -d /home/"$response"/backup/ ]; then echo "This user has not created the /home/"$response"/backup/ folder yet!"; exit; fi
cp /home/"$response"/file.txt /home/"$response"/backup/file_backup.txt
exit
```

**Edit**: the code above was edited to add a few improvements.

Comment: Nice. I like it. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using `getent passwd` rather than referring to `/etc/passwd` directly -- that way this will support systems using NIS, LDAP, or other directory services as well rather than being limited to local-file-authentication only. You might also explicitly provide a nonzero exit status for the error cases. (In the non-erroneous case, by contrast, the default behavior of exiting with the status of the last command -- that of `cp` -- is probably the Right Thing; by putting in an explicit `exit 0`, you have a successful exit status even if `cp` failed).

Comment: Thanks Charles! I love `getent`, I had never heard of it before. Also, the final `exit` should not be set to zero -- I developed a lot for very beginner users (beginners like doesn't know how to double click!) and I normally make the code as silent as possible, so that was just the habit, but regular `exit` here is much better. I fixed my answer.